# Xfce4 Panel Launcher Menu as Desktop icon

Tags: launcher, xfce, .desktop, plugins, xfce-panel

I'm trying to create a launcher like the one you can add to the panel on the desktop in Xfce. There is a create launcher option I'm aware, and the launcher is the same as one on the panel, but the difference is the panel plugin that allows you to add a group of applications to a launcher and such. I'm doing this for my dad and I've already written a .desktop file that makes an icon that opens the applicationsmenu plugin at the pointer once the icon is clicked, but I can't reuse the code from it. Hope anyone can give some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before you log in, there is a button right next to the password prompt which allows you to select it on-screen.

Once you are in, the best way to switch is to log back out then make the other selection.

```
They cannot run at the same time on the same console.
```

I do know that when I use VNC to open a second console I can get the xfce desktop.

Each console will have only a single environment.

So perhaps you could create an icon that launches VNC into your own machine.

Comment: I'm sorry? That has nothing to do w/ it, I'm trying to create a grouped launcher like you can on the panel on the desktop by creating a .desktop file that works. Nothing to do w/ logging in, I'm very confused. I know how to switch Desktop Environments.